# Creating new objects with Django ModelForm

Tags: django, forms, model

I created a view where users could update subscriptions in their profiles, but when i went to add a new user i realized that i hadn't figured in creating new subscriptions.  So what i had was:

models.py

```
class Customer_Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    customers = models.ManyToManyField('Customers', blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.user)
```

forms.py

```
class CustomerSubscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer_Subscription
        fields = ['customers']
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cust_subscription_instance = Customer_Subscription.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
        customer_subscription = CustomerSubscriptionForm(request.POST, instance=cust_subscription_instance)
        if customer_subscription.is_valid() and level_subscription.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            customer_subscription.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
```

Since there was no instance of the Customer_Subscription object that query was failing.  I've tried several things as "exceptions" but none seem to work, and i don't know which if any are close to being correct.  Looking for some help.

views.py

```
try:
    cust_subscription_instance = Customer_Subscription.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    customer_subscription = CustomerSubscriptionForm(request.POST, instance=cust_subscription_instance)
    if customer_subscription.is_valid() and level_subscription.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        customer_subscription.save(commit=True)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
except:
    customer_subscription = CustomerSubscriptionForm(request.user.id, request.POST)
    if customer_subscription.is_valid():
        customer_subscription.save(commit=True)
         level_subscription.save(commit=True)
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_or_create`;

```
Customer_Subscription.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

to create `Customer_Subscription` object if it isn't exist.

Comment: Thanks.  Subbing this in actually gave me an error because i didn't realize it returned a tuple.  Resolved by declaring as     cust_subscription_instance, created = Customer_Subscription.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot to mention that :/

Answer (score 3):

views.py

```
class ViewSuccess(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'frontend/view_success.html'

class CreateCustomerSubscription(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'frontend/create_customer_subscription.html'
    success_url = 'frontend:view_success'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('frontend:view_success')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        try:
            return self.request.user.customersubscription
        except CustomerSubscription.DoesNotExist:
            return CustomerSubscription.objects.create(user=self.request.user)


    def get_form_class(self):
        class _Form(forms.ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = CustomerSubscription
                fields = ['customers']

        return _Form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)

        self.object.user = self.request.user              
        self.object.save()

        form.save_m2m()

        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CreateCustomerSubscription, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

models.py

```
class CustomerSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    customers = models.ManyToManyField('Customer', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^create/$', CreateCustomerSubscription.as_view(), name='create_customer_subscription'),
    url(r'^success/$', ViewSuccess.as_view(), name="view_success")
)
```

and create_customer_subscription.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content_main %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, use the DoesNotExists to check get failure. Wrap only the get call with it.

```
try:
    cust_subscription_instance = Customer_Subscription.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
except Customer_Subscription.DoesNotExists:
    cust_subscription_instance = None
```